# How should I know the questions for which I have received curious badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

Recently I got a badge in Stack Overflow named ["Curious badge"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious). It is said that that badge is awarded when `"Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record"`

How do I know the questions for which I have been awarded with this badge?

Comment: I got the badge yesterday, but there was no upvote on any question in the last days. I thought it was a bug in the curious badge asignment.

Comment: @Alex The badge is new, so a whole lot of people that would have been eligible a long time ago just got it.

Comment: You can view where are are with the "well received question on X separate days" criteria with [this Data.SE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202534/asking-over-time-badges?bronze=5&silver=30&gold=100), however as of right now [there is no way for users to view their "Positive Question Record"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234963/how-can-i-see-what-my-positive-question-record-score-is?rq=1#comment772715_234963) unless you have no deleted questions, and want to do the math yourself based on your user profile.

Comment: You truly ARE curious!

Answer (score 34):

The precise criteria for this badge are in [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges); it's a bit [more complicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234956/misleading-description-of-new-curious-badge) than the short one-sentence description makes it seem.

Depending on your view point, there are two possible answers to your question "Which questions did I receive the badge for?".

1. **All of them**. Every single question you asked comes into play for this badge. If it's upvoted and open, it counts towards a "good day". If it's downvoted or closed, it counts for a "bad day". And all your questions count for the formula `(total - negative - closed - deleted)/total >= 0.5` as well.
2. **None of them.** The main criteria for earning the badge isn't really about the number of *questions*, but rather about the number of *days*. So you could say that you earned the badge for August 19, August 22, September 2, September 4, and September 5 of 2013. But that's of course not a very useful response.

The bottom line is, this badge is awarded for the whole of your question-asking activity, and not any set of specific questions.

Comment: Your formula doesn't take into account if a question is upvoted... all it does it remove negative, closed and deleted questions.  Is your formula wrong, or does the question have to have >= 0 votes?

Comment: @freefaller The formula counts the number of questions (which have a negative score, are closed, are deleted, …), not the score of one question.

Comment: @Blackhole, I understand that.  But balpha states that a "good day" has upvotes and is open.  And a "bad day" is downvoted, closed or deleted.  The formula is <strike>missing</strike> *including* those which are open with zero votes

Comment: @freefaller There are two criteria for the badge (details [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259)). The "positive question record" part is the formula you're talking about, and if you had only 0-score questions and no closed or deleted ones, you're good for that requirement (your score is 1.0 in that case). For the "well-received question on X separate days" part however, you actually need a question of score 1 and no questions of negative score (or closed/deleted) for a particular day. Put differently, a >0 question counts *for* you, and a >=0 question does *not* count *against* you.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for the clarification @balpha

Comment: @balpha: Does that mean a bad question can counter 3 good questions for positive balance? Or is your formula wrong?

Comment: @Deduplicator Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: It's just the formula you wrote down. Do you really mean `total - negative - closed - negated` or `#(total - negative - closed - deleted) == #(all that are neither negative, closed nor deleted)`?

Comment: @Deduplicator No, I meant exactly what I wrote. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges.