# Next badge fulfilled, but it is still showing in "next badge"

Tags: discussion, badge-progress

I could not understand: Is it bug or something? I have fulfilled the criteria of the badge, and it is also showing fulfilled (5/5), but it is still in "next badge". What is happening?

[image]

I have at least the following five positive question records:

1. [RTL characters in display name reverse badge/rep display as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299339/rtl-characters-in-display-name-reverse-badge-rep-display-as-well)
2. [What about this reviewed rejection?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299246/what-about-this-reviewed-rejection)
3. [Why there is no link in “peer reviewed” while editing tag wiki?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/why-there-is-no-link-in-peer-reviewed-while-editing-tag-wiki)
4. [What to do when a link refers to a non-English site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299656/what-to-do-when-a-link-refers-to-a-non-english-site)
5. [What to do when a tag is misspelled? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299289/what-to-do-when-a-tag-is-misspelled)

If you think the last one is not granted for having duplicate, then I have another question that is not duplicate:

[Where to ask competitive programming related problems actually?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298212/where-to-ask-competitive-programming-related-problems-actually)

Comment: I find it confusing too.  Maybe the count should reset as soon as you have a non zero record score.

Comment: Do you have any deleted questions? That could maybe be why you haven't fulfilled the positive question record requirement.

Comment: The line directly below that says "need positive question record" with an "x" next to it indicating you haven't fulfilled that part of the badge requirement.

Comment: related/maybe dup https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262391/how-should-i-know-the-questions-for-which-i-have-received-curious-badge

Comment: @animuson, yes  and my further discussion was for that. What does it mean actually?

Comment: The formula is `(total questions - downvoted - early deleted - early closed) / total questions >= 0.5` where "early" means within 60 days of it being posted.

Comment: same issue here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303680/im-curious-why-i-havent-gotten-the-curious-badge

Comment: @CRABOLO, both of your questions are after getting the badge, but my question is prior to getting badge. Some answers are similar, but not exactly same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the moderator [animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson)'s [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305354/next-badge-fulfilled-but-it-is-still-showing-in-next-badge?noredirect=1#comment243470_305354) the answer is:

There is a cross sign (`x`), just after the green progress bar where it is written: *"need positive question record"* which means the following equation must be fulfilled:

( *total questions minus downvoted questions minus questions deleted in last 60 days minus questions closed in last 60 days* ) divided by total questions needs to be greater than or equal to 0.5

[image: Image of formula]